# My font keep revert to "Times new roman" But I'm I set "Metropolis" in the script

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects

```js
var parent = app.project.activeItem;

for(var i = 0; i < parent.layers.length; i++){
        var mySourceText = parent.layer(i + 1).property("ADBE Text Properties").property("ADBE Text Document");
        var textProp = parent.layer(i + 1).property("Source Text");
        var currentValue = textProp.value;
        if(currentValue.toString().match(/[a-z]/i)){
            currentValue.font = "Bodoni-BoldMT";
            currentValue.fontSize = 125;
            textProp.setValue(currentValue);
            $.writeln("alpha hai ", currentValue)
        }else if(currentValue.toString().match(/[0-9]/i)){
            var myTextDoc = mySourceText.value;
            myTextDoc.fontSize = 100;
            myTextDoc.font = "Metropolis-Bold";
            myTextDoc.fillColor = [0.5,0.5,0];
            mySourceText.setValue(myTextDoc);  
            $.writeln("number hai ", currentValue)
        }else if(currentValue.toString().match(/[+\-=]/i)){
            currentValue.font = "Times New Roman";
            $.writeln("Arrtmathic hai ", currentValue)
        }else{
           $.writeln("Missed ", currentValue)
        }
}
```

Comment: It's probably reverting because your font cannot render a particular glyph that the data references.  Your font choice will revert to default  when that is the case.   Not all fonts are designed with every single UTF-8 glyph .

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I resolved this issue by select font name from after effects. when you select a specific font from after effects it's returns you a name with some prefixes and that will be working

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me that the font name is spelled incorrectly. try to set the necessary one first and pull out all the correct values from it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WXrF.png)